# ConfigurationLoadError: Unable to load configuration file

Tags: configuration, anaconda, conda, miniconda

I have no idea why but I am unable to use conda within terminal. Conda command results in "ConfigurationLoadError"

```
ConfigurationLoadError: Unable to load configuration file.
  path: /Users/kiranmarathe/.condarc
  reason: invalid yaml at line 2, column 42
```

kiranmarathe$ cat /Users/kiranmarathe/.condarc

```
channels:
  - defaults    
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
  - http://conda.binstar.org/faircloth-lab
```

Comment: Can edit your question and add the output of `cat /Users/kiranmarathe/.condarc`?

Comment: I have edited the question. The output of kiranmarathe$ cat /Users/kiranmarathe/.condarc is channels:
  - defaults 
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
  - http://conda.binstar.org/faircloth-lab

Answer (score 5):

Go to the `/Users/kiranmarathe/` path and delete the `.condarc` file. I think the issue will be resolved.